Polygon contract deployment takes long, really long
I am trying to deploy a smart contract with an NFT collection erc721, however I did the deployment couple of hours ago and still is not visible yet on polygon scan, I tried deploying several times, no errors however on harhat deployment comand, just printing the contract address that I then checked but again,empty page.

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MintingThings is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string private baseExtension;
    string public notRevealedTokenUri;
    //Override switches
    bool public paused = true;
    bool public revealed = true;
    bool public multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet = true;

    // check the max supply
    uint256 public maxSupply = 60; //adjust with image nmber

    event Minted(uint256 tokenId);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initNotRevealedTokenUri,
        string memory _baseUri,
        string memory _baseExtension
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        notRevealedTokenUri = _initNotRevealedTokenUri;
        baseURI = _baseUri;
        baseExtension = _baseExtension;
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // internal
    function _notRevealedTokenUri()
        internal
        view
        virtual
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return notRevealedTokenUri;
    }

    // only owner.
    function mintTo(address to) external onlyOwner {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 tokenId = supply + 1;
        bool alreadyMinted = balanceOf(to) > 0;

        require(!paused, "Minting not allowed");

        require(supply < maxSupply, "No more NFTs remaining");

        if (!multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet)
            require(!alreadyMinted, "wallet already have the nft");

        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        emit Minted(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "tokenId provided doesn't exist");

        if (revealed == false) {
            return notRevealedTokenUri;
        }

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function toggleReveal() external onlyOwner {
        revealed = !revealed;
    }

    function setNotRevealedTokenURI(string memory _notRevealedTokenURI)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        notRevealedTokenUri = _notRevealedTokenURI;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) external onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function setPaused(bool _state) external onlyOwner {
        paused = _state;
    }

    function toggleAllowMultipleMintsPerWallet() external onlyOwner {
        multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet = !multipleMintsAllowedPerWallet;
    }

    function burnAll() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 currentSupply = totalSupply();
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= currentSupply; i++) {
            _burn(i);
        }
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function setMaxSupply(uint256 _maxSupply) public onlyOwner {
        maxSupply = _maxSupply;
    }
}

I deployed several times since there was nothign being deployed, probably a mistake, but was not sure what the problem was, I see now after loging on one of the deployments that
Transaction hash: 0xd78aaec758d1af0c0066f4dbea833a6a0e0730c18efe484545e5dfe1b5079a6f
Contract deployed in block: 63683589
Contract deployed to: 0x6fb7CFC8ca9AA8A2e0903e4A4BC014C16668854c

I can see on the transaction hash 0xd78aaec758d1af0c0066f4dbea833a6a0e0730c18efe484545e5dfe1b5079a6f that is being indexed, and i am not sure why this is happening neither what it means exactly or if there is something I can do to solve this situation and get my contracts deployed, thanks a lot for your time and any guidance is more than welcome.

May be you need to increase the gas while deploying to make it more competitive for confirming the transaction on network.

thanks for the answer, I tried that but seems the problem was an unscheduled maintance from poligonScan api which caused some transactions to stay in indexing status
